# Read DPI of Image-File

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Good morning,

I want to crop pictures through VBA-Code. Due to the reason that images can occur in two different resolutions (96x96 DPI and 300x300 DPI) I need to know what res. the image-file has to crop it correctly. The file format of those images is .tif.

On the internet I found following code which uses a FSO to get the image file attributes:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Debug.Print fso.GetFile("C:\Users\...\Downloads\75.tif").Attributes '<-- 32
```

This is where it gets complicated. I can only see how many attributes an image has but cant get further into them. There is more code [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?371643-Get-the-DPI-of-an-jpg-image-)) but this one only works for jpg format.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

You can use the `Shell.Application` object to retrieve file details. The `DPI` is spread out over two properties. The `Horizontal Resolution` and the `Vertical Resolution`.

Here's a brief example that will iterate a folder and give you the DPI for each image.

```
Sub getResolution()
    Const HorizontalRes As Integer = 161
    Const VerticalRes As Integer = 163

    Dim i       As Long
    Dim wsh     As Object: Set wsh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Dim fileObj As Object
    Dim foldObj As Object
    Dim Folder  As Object
    Dim vRes    As String
    Dim hRes    As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the Folder..."
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            Set foldObj = wsh.Namespace(.SelectedItems(1))

            For Each fileObj In foldObj.Items
                vRes = foldObj.GetDetailsOf(fileObj, HorizontalRes)
                hRes = foldObj.GetDetailsOf(fileObj, VerticalRes)

                MsgBox fileObj.Name & vbCrLf & _
                       "Horizontal Resolution: " & hRes & vbCrLf & _
                       "Vertical Resolution: " & vRes
            Next
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I found `175` for horizontal resolution (dpi), `176` for width in pixel, `177` for vertical resolution (dpi) and `178` for height in pixel. The image file is a .PNG-File.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering. Your code is nearly the same one I am using currently. I just need one resolution so I did not write a second value. Furthermore I do some string adjustments because it returns

> "?96 dpi"

So I am able to return the DPI value with one command. Here's the code I am using. I hope this helps other people as well!

```
Public Function getDPI() As Integer

    Dim objShell
    Dim objFolder
'   Dim i

    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("edit path here") ' <-- ToDo

    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objFolderItem

        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("edit filename here") ' <-- ToDo

        If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
            Dim objInfo
'            For i = 1 To 288
               getDPI = Trim(Mid(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 161), 2, 3)) ' <--161 represents the horizontal resolution
'            Next
        End If

        Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Function
```